# Hide IE instance when executing Coded-UI tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'd like to be able to run my Coded-UI tests on a headless browser.  Is there some way for me to hide the IE browser instance when executing my tests?

Comment: Again, who is down voting the coded ui questions and not leaving any comment as to why.  This is a perfectly valid question, imo.

Comment: Maybe someone from Selenium?!?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions.

- Can you run Coded UI tests on a headless browser?
- Can you hide the IE browser instance when executing tests?

Coded UI tests can be run on a Virtual Machine (VM) (or even a physical computer) where no display is connected. To do this both the application under test and the Visual Studio that runs the tests must be running on that VM. The application under test could be a browser. Visual Studio also has an "agent" software that can run a test under the control of Visual Studio, or MTM or programs like `mstest.exe`.

Coded UI runs tests by running the application under test. If that application is a browser then that browser must be running and must be displaying its output on a screen. The screen may on a remote physical or virtual computer and does not need to be shown on any real screen. It is common to have a remote desktop to access the computer running the tests, but to have that desktop not in focus while the tests run. If the remote desktop is minimised or if it starts running a screensaver then the test will fail.

Comment: I'll add a comment here - you can't minimize the RDP session and still have CodedUI tests execute. 

If you ever do remote into a test agent machine and interact with the desktop, you'll need to restart the VM and login automatically to run UI tests again.

Comment: @Ryanman Thank you for pointing this out. There are several web pages around discussing this, a web search for "coded ui remote desktop minimise" finds some of them.